# How to fix frayed carpet at tile transition

Tags: carpet

I have a carpet/tile transition where the carpet is becoming frayed.  Pictures below for reference.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to fix this.  I don't have any spare carpet samples to use for patching.  I'm not entirely sure, but I think this may have started because the padding under the carpet was not cut properly and it prevented the carpet from sticking to the transition strip spikes.

I'm not sure if it would be better to try and find a different transition strip that would cover the frayed area, or try to pull the carpet back, cut off the frayed area and re-attach the carpet to the strip (fixing the poor padding cut job in the process).  If I were to cut off a quarter-half inch of this carpet would I even be able to pull it forward? Any advice would be greatly appreciated
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I installed carpet with a professional for two years right out of college.  I don't think you need to buy anything.  You need to pry the lip of that transition piece up so you can get the carpet loose along the entire length, then stretch the carpet forward more with a knee kicker.  You can hold the carpet in place with the kicker while you use a rubber mallet to hammer down and lock the carpet under the transition again.  If the carpet is frayed bad, you can trim a little to give the tabs more meat to grab onto.  Most guys could do this in 5 minutes.  If you call a local installer and ask him to swing by one day when they are in the area, they may do it for $50 cash.

Comment: This is a good solution but not DIY right?

Comment: I think it is DIY personally.  Renting a kicker will cost you $20 for the day, or go buy a cheap one at harbor freight for $40.

Comment: You do not need to stretch out a whole wall to do a small section.

Comment: If you only stretch the frayed section to the transition, you may end up with a bubble popping up on either side.  It really does not look like a difficult repair.  I suggest buying the cheapest kicker you can find and giving it a go.  Worse case: you have to trim the entire length and put down a new strip.  It should be stretched with a kicker regardless though.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, but I think I will try the least invasive approach (not cutting) first and see where I'm at.  Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally buy a thicker transition piece.  Then cut your carpet out a 1/4-1/2" and retuck.  After you get it in place I would reinforce with some staples.  Or even better buy a transition piece that allows for the carpet to be placed under part of it.

Comment: Even if you cut the carpet back and use a wider transitional piece, the carpet should still be kicked/stretched so that is catches on the tack strip and sets in place.

Comment: OK I have changed transitions on maybe a 100 thresholds.  You do NOT need to stretch an entire wall because of a small section.  The sections right around this are still stretched.  So a little pull with your hand and a good transition and it is good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Bend up the metal transition with a flathead screwdriver, also pull back carpet along the entire side - just off the tackstrip of where the transition sits.

Then starting in the middle, kick to the left or right all the way to the corner - tuck it, then kick from the middle to the other side and tuck. You can use a rubber mallet or a hammer using a towel to bend the metal transition back down.